# ¿Cómo instalar/configurar tkinter en Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sublimetext3

Tengo tiempo usando el IDLE que trae python por defecto y todo funciona bastante bien, pero ahora que quiero ponerme con el tkinter me parece más cómodo en Sublime Text 3 y sorpresa, no puedo importarlo.

```
import tkinter
```

Con solo este fragmento de código ya da el siguiente error:

```
File "C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
import tkinter
File "C:\Users\Mauricio\Desktop\tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
tk=Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

He buscado información y en la mayoría de sitios llegan a la conclusión de que no está instalado o algo similar, aunque en el IDLE que trae por defecto python me funciona perfectamente, así que es cosa de Sublime Text 3 y en ninguno de estos sitios web no dan solución, solo dicen cual es el problema.

Nota: por si las dudas, de momento solo me sucede esto cuando importo tkinter, hacer import os o similares funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es que tkinter no este instalado, el problema es que importas tkinter de esta forma `import tkinter` y para acceder a las clases de tkinter tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

`root = tkinter.Tk()` ya que sino lo haces el interprete de python no sabe que Tk() pertenece a la clase tkinter

Tambien podrias importar tkinter de la siguiente manera:
`from tkinter import *` y asi no tienes que escribir `tkinter.` antes de crear un objeto de alguna clase de tkinter, aunque no es muy recomendada ya que se pueden crear problemas con alguna clase o metodo que tu hayas declarado con el mismo nombre que alguna de tkinter.

Yo te recomiendo que para importar tkinter lo hagas de la siguiente manera:
`import tkinter as tk` y cuando vayas a usar las clases simplemente hagas los siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk() #Crear ventana principal

button = tk.Button(root,text="Hola Stack Overflow").pack() #Crear boton usando tkinter

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Lo logré solucionar antes de la respuesta ¿Cómo? borré todos los archivos/carpetas que tenían relación e intenté importar tkinter  en un archivo nuevo y problema solucionado, realmente no sé cuál era el error.

Comment: @Mauricio si tienes un archivo con el nombre del módulo a importar, Python va a importar TU módulo con el mismo nombre, no el "verdadero" tkinter, que es parte de la standard lib... Básicamente, el intérprete entra en conflicto y no sabe qué archivo quieres leer